# compute datatable with many filters

Tags: vb.net, datatable

data table with 3 columns ( Quantity - SOP_Type - Item_Number)
I want to compute sum of column Quantity for the item with number "309-032-SHU" and SOP_Type = 3
I tried this code and didn't work

```
Dim b As String
b = "309-032-SHU"
dim c as integer
c = 3
       
DGV1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = NAJRNDataSet.vwSalesLineItems.Compute("SUM(Quantity)", "Item_Number = " & b & " ", "SOP_Type = " & c & " ")
```

Comment: The filter is simply a Boolean expression. How do you usually combine multiple Boolean conditions into a compound statement? If you don't know that, stop what you're doing and do some research on Boolean logic, because you can't really do programming without understanding that.

Comment: In fact, the documentation for the method even provides an example. Don't ask questions here without reading the relevant documentation first. All you had to do was click the method name and press the F1 key. Context-sensitive Help has been a thing in Windows for decades, so you don't really need programming experience for that.

Comment: thanks for your advice and i will do some research on Boolean logic , if you can edit my code i will be thankful , and i need your advice to how to start leaning visual basic programing

Comment: Here is a tutorial that you can start with: [VbTutorial](https://www.vblessons.com/lessons.html) and also here : [VB.NET Tutorial and source code](http://vb.net-informations.com/). good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since DataTable class does not implement IEnumerable it provides an extension method to get an enumerable. (`.AsEnumerable`) We can then use a linq syntax to get the Sum.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'Fill the datatable
    Dim b = "309-032-SHU"
    Dim c = 3
    Dim Total As Integer
    Total = (From r As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable
             Where r.Field(Of String)("Item_Number") = b And r.Field(Of Integer)("SOP_Type") = c
             Select r.Field(Of Integer)("Quantity")).Sum
    DGV1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = Total
End Sub
```

Comment: i am very thankful for your help ,when i use this code it take to much time to run because i have very large Database so i need a code without looping every row,  for example like method "compute" that i used in my question i hope you can help me i need this code badly to finish my accounting work

Comment: How many rows are we talking about? Linq is not known for speed. No matter what method you use, every row must be inspected and this must be done in a loop visible to you or inside a .Compute.

Comment: 98,000 rows and every row will looping 11,000 times to find the item row

Comment: i have datatable contain 98000 rows every row have column for the quantity and the sop_type and the item number

and i have datagridview contain 11000 rows every row have column for the item number

i need to sum the quantity  of every item in the datatable and copy the summation to the datagridview in the item row